# Chrome not rendering canvas data as expected [JS/Canvas API]

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, image-processing, html5-canvas

I have a function which I have altered from an answer on codegolf (since the original answer didn't actually work).

Basically all it does is takes the pixels of an image, scrambles them up and then outputs the scrambled image onto the page.

Here is my code as it stands:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    img {
      min-width: 500px;
      min-height: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="test.jpg" alt="" />
  <script>
    function scramble(el) {
      "use strict";
      var V = document.createElement('canvas');
      var W = V.width = el.width,
        H = V.height = el.height,
        C = V.getContext('2d');

      C.drawImage(el, 0, 0);

      var id = C.getImageData(0, 0, W, H),
        D = id.data,
        L = D.length,
        i = L / 4,
        A = [];

      for (; --i;) A[i] = i;

      function S(A) {
        var L = A.length,
          x = L >> 3,
          y, t, i = 0,
          s = [];

        if (L < 8) return A;

        for (; i < L; i += x) s[i / x] = S(A.slice(i, i + x));

        for (i = 4; --i;) y = [6, 4, 7, 5, 1, 3, 0, 2][i], t = s[i], s[i] = s[y], s[y] = t;

        s = [].concat.apply([], s);

        return s;
      }
      var N = C.createImageData(W, H),
        d = N.data,
        A = S(A);

      for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) d[i] = D[(A[i >> 2] * 4) + (i % 4)];

      C.putImageData(N, 0, 0);

      el.src = C.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    }

    scramble(document.querySelector("img"));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, the issue is with chrome, unlike FF, Edge and IE, which all display as expected, chrome just shows a black square where the image should be.

I can't for the life of me figure out why, especially since all the other browsers work as expected.

Here is a screenshot of the other browsers showing fine and chrome with the black square.

[image]

As you can see, all of the other browsers are fine, chrome however just doesn't do as expected, nor does it throw any console errors or have any visible telltale reason for not working which is frustrating.

Anyway, any questions, ask below in the comments.

Comment: There is no CORS data though, it is a local image being loaded...?

Comment: Have you tried calling `scramble` at `load` event of `<img>` element?

Comment: It works!... why the hell does the onload event need fired though, the parser should render the image into the DOM before executing the script, no?

Comment: The `<img>` may not be fully loaded when `scramble` is called

Comment: Accept guest's answer, it answered the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `scramble` at `load` event of `<img>` element

```
document.querySelector("img").onload = function() {
   scramble(this)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code provided
document.querySelector("img").onload = function() {
scramble(this)
};
makes the image scramble and unscramble very rapidly.
It does not create a static scrambled rendering.
Furthermore, the absence of the code leaves Chrome
displaying the static form of the original
unscrambled image.